# How can I call a function from a controller in a subdirectory - Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to make a web app, without using a Framework like Revel and just using the Gorilla toolkit,

So far I have structured my app like this:

```
/App
- Controllers
   - Index.go
- Views
   - Index.html
- Public
   - css
   - js
   - img
- main.go
```

My `main.go` looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/", Index)

    http.Handle("/", r)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

And `Index.go` looks like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func Index(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Here")
}
```

But when I `go run main.go` it says Index is undefined, I'm not sure how to call functions from another file in a subdirectory. Any information would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go convention prevents this.  You must keep Index() within the main package.

Once you have some code that can be separated out, you will then create a sub-directory (package) and import it into main.

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Answer (score 0):

[Go code organization rules](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization) require one directory per package. Since your package `main` is split over the root directory and the `controllers` directory, your code organization won't work.

You can either make `controllers` a package and then import it into `main`, which I'd only recommend if you are projecting for a large codebase, or simply relocate the controllers file to the root directory.